# php - how do I change the color of a word in the middle of the sentence

Tags: php, css

How can I change the color of the word "Validação"? Thank you

```
echo "A Aguardar <b>Validação</b>";
```

Comment: Using css, you can add class to the `<b>` tag.

Comment: Have you even tried to google this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this, search with tag and text and replace with css of it

```
$str = "A Aguardar <b>Validação</b>";
$str = str_replace("<b>Validação</b>","<b style='color:red'>Validação</b>",$str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing color is a CSS task.

You can add it by using adding a CSS class/ID to it:

Steps:

1) Add class `special` to respective text string.

2) Define the class body using `<style>` attribute.

```
<?php
echo 'A Aguardar <b class="special">Validação</b>';
?>

<style>
    .special {
       color: yellow;
    }
</style>
```